# Die Partikel »gwe«

Tags: meaning, etymology, austrian, particle

In Österreich hört man manchmals umgangssprachlich das kleine bedeutungslose Wort *gwe,* das am Ende von einem Satz angefügt wird, nur um sich die Aufmerksamkeit vom Zuhörer zu versichern, ungefähr mit der Bedeutung *nicht wahr.* Die Schreibweise kenne ich nicht, ich habe das Wort nur phonetisch geschrieben.

Ich möchte wissen, woher das Wort kommt und ob es das gleiche Wort ist wie *gell.* Gerne würde ich auch wissen, wie verbreitet es ist; ich habe es v.a. in Oberösterreich gehört.

Comment: Vielleicht relevant: http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_2/f19a-b/index.html

Comment: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f19a-b/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ich würde es nicht »gwe« schreiben, sondern »gö« oder eher »göh« (mit stummen h). Eigentlich ist es »göl« mit einem stummen l, das man oft in österreichischen Dialekten findet. Es ist die Dialekt-Version des Wortes »gell«. Die Lautfolgen »ell« und »el« werden in Österreich (und wie ich vermute auch in Bayern) gerne als langgezogenes »ö« ausgesprochen (eigentlich »öl« mit unhörbarem, aber mitgedachtem l):

> Es ist schon **hell**. - Es is scho **hö**.
>   Ich fahre heute von **Melk** nach **Wels**. - I foa heit fu **Mök** noch **Wös**.
>   Du bist schon älter als zwölf, **gell**? - Du bist scho öta ois zwöf, **gö**?

Das Wort »*gell*« hat genau die Bedeutung von »nicht wahr«, das an eine Feststellung angefügt wird, um daraus eine Frage nach der Richtigkeit dieser Feststellung zu machen.

Feststellung:

> Du bist schon älter als zwölf.

Frage, ob die angesprochene Person wirklich älter als zwölf ist:

> Du bist schon älter als zwölf, **nicht wahr**?
>   Du bist schon älter als zwölf, **gell**?

Die Fragepartikel »*gell*« (außerhalb Österreich findet man auch die Form »*gelle*«) leitet sich vom Verb »gelten« ab und ist laut Duden, Herkunftswörterbuch eine verkürzte Form der dritten Person Singular Konjunktiv von »gelten«: »Es möge gelten«.

---

Fragepartikel (einzelne Wörter, die einen Satz zu einer Frage machen) kommen im Standarddeutsch nicht vor. »Gell« (und »gelle«) findet man daher nur in der Umgangssprache und in Dialekten. In anderen Sprachen (Arabisch, Thai, Türkisch) sind Fragepartikel fester Bestandteil der Standardsprache.

Andere Fragepartikel, die in Österreich in einigen Dialekten vorkommen sind »a« (nur am Beginn eines Satzes in Kärntner Dialekten), »ha« (nur am Ende einer Frage) und, soweit ich weiß auch außerhalb Österreichs, »ob« (am Beginn eines Satzes):

> **A** da Wulfgang kummt heit? = **A** der Wolfgang kommt heute? = Stimmt es, dass Wolgang heute kommt?
>   **A** kunst du ma an Euro leichn? = **A** kannst du mir einen Euro leihen? = Würdest du mir bitte einen Euro geben?
>
> Da Otto is a festa Dogga, **ha**? = Der Otto ist ein fester Idiot, **ha**? = Habe ich damit recht, dass Otto ein Idiot ist?
>
> **Ob**'s heit regnt? = **Ob** es heute regnet? = Wird es heute regnen?

Die Kärntnerische Fragepartikel »a« darf übrigens nicht mit der Interjektion »ach« verwechselt werden. Eine Interjektion macht aus seiner Aussage keine Frage:

> Ach, da Otto is do. = Ach, Otto ist da. - Einfache Aussage, keine Frage, sondern simple Feststellung einer Tatsache.
>
> A da Otto is do? = Stimmt es, dass Otto da ist? - Das ist eine Frage, keine Feststellung.

---

Zur Verbreitung kann ich nur sagen, dass »gö/gell« in Österreich sehr verbreitet ist, aber nicht überall gleich ausgesprochen wird.

Ganz im Osten (Burgenland, Wien, Osthälfte Niederösterreichs) und im Süden (Steiermark, Kärnten) ist es definitiv »gö« mit einem langen ö.

An der Alpennordseite, westlich von St. Pölten, wird das »gö« immer mehr zu »gei« ([geɪ̯], nicht [gaɪ̯]), je weiter man nach Westen geht. Daher hört man in Oberösterreich auch eher [geɪ̯] als ein [gøː].

In Tirol wird das Wort als »gell«, mit kurzem, scharfen e ausgesprochen.

In Vorarlberg ist »gö/gei/gell« nicht gebräuchlich. Dort findet man stattdessen, an derselben Stelle im Satz, die Partikel »odr« (»oder« ohne e aber mit sehr deutlich hörbarem, gerolltem r, also [ˈoːdʀ]).

Comment: Danke sehr für die Antworte!  Die Verwendung von gell (gelt, gö) war mir schon klar, jetzt weiß ich, daß diese Aussprache nur eine Variante ist.

Comment: In Ostbayern wird *-ell* auch zu *-ö*, die Westbayern machen sich darüber lustig (Westen: *hei, Fei, Gstei* statt *hell, Fell, Gestell*)

Comment: Es gibt auch in Vorarlberg eine Version von »gell« und zwar »gea« (sehr schnell ausgesprochen und das g stark betont). Es ist allerdings im Vergleich zu »odr« selten zu hören und kann auch als starke Zustimmung gebraucht werden etwa: »Isch des langwilig – Gea!« (Ist das langweilig – Stimmt!/Denke ich mir auch!)

Answer (score 5):

Die Herkunft dieses Satzzusatzes kenne ich nicht, aber ja es ist eine lokale in Österreich vorkommende Interpetation von 'gell'. 
Im norddeutschen zum Beispiel wird häufig der Laut 'Ne' am Ende eines Satzes platziert, ebenfalls mit dem Zweck der Zustimmung, bzw. Bestätigung der Aufmerksamkeit des Zuhörers